# How to disable Palm Detection/Exclusion on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 19.10, synaptics

I want one very simple thing, I want to keep my touchpad always enabled when typing and I want the entire touchpad working no matter where I start my tapping from. Just to be clear, I do not want to disable the touchpad, I just do not want palm detection in any form, at all, ever.

I have a `Synaptics TM2722-001` touchpad according to `xinput`.

I've tried the suggestions from older answers, there's no `DisableWhileTyping` or `Synaptics Palm Detection` property so those solutions unfortunately don't work in this case.

How would I go about to achieve this?